# How can I create httpBody correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, http, content-type

I want to create the body of POST method with

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

I'have got a dictionary

```
let params = ["key":"val","key1":"val1"]
```

I've tried to convert and escape dictionary using `URLComponents`. But have not found in the HTTP specifications those escape methods are the same.

Does somebody know a correct solution to do this?

I've looked at

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hoehrmann-urlencoded-01

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1866

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986

Comment: You need url encoded in the body?

Comment: Can u be more specific what u want to achieve

Comment: @ReinierMelian yes. I'm not sure that URLComponents.query is a correct implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can and should create the body with `NSURLComponents`:

```
let components = NSURLComponents()

components.queryItems = [ 
    URLQueryItem(name: "key", value: "val"), 
    URLQueryItem(name: "key1", value: "val1")
]
if let query = components.query {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest()

    request.url = ...
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = [ "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]
    request.httpBody = query.data(using: .utf8)
}
```

`NSURLComponents` creates valid URLs from data, and parses valid URLs to its components. The body of a HTTP post request with the content type above should contain the parameters as URL query (see [How are parameters sent in an HTTP POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request)).

`NSURLComponents` is a good choice because it ensures conformity to the standard.

see also: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application/x-www-form-urlencoded_type) and [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1).

Comment: I said I did the same. I'm not sure that this is a correct implementation

Comment: @clement I did the same.

Comment: the stackoverflow url is not a specification

Comment: `s/t/s/`; Than everything is fine. ;)

Comment: everything is fine. ;) > nice evidence ;)

Comment: i just upvote due to you did some work but this is not the answer

Comment: I've added a link to the W3C standard, and hope fine things become better. ;)

Comment: 10x. Ok. You won :)

Comment: @clemens URLQueryItem only supports String type but what about handling other types?

Comment: You have convert them to strings.